# What is correct name for PowerShell commandlet that replaces something

Tags: powershell

The only problem with Replace-Something name is:

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'Xxxx' include
 unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands
with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose
parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
```

What is correct name for commandlet that will replace some content?

Get-Verb does not seem to have anything suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about 'Set'. Like in Set-Content which implies replacing whatever is already there.

Or `Update` (Data) or `Out` -Force (Data) if you writing a file.

Comment: It will replace part's of content. Something like Set-ContentWithReplacedParts. English is not my native and I cannot think of something good.

Comment: @MikeChaliy In that case Update is better suited.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/07/15/final-approved-verb-list-for-windows-powershell-2-0.aspx) is a post giving the list of approved verbs for powershell 2.0.  I'd suggest "Update".

Answer (score -2):

Run the Get-Verb cmdlet and use anything you see listed.